# Database error - can't select data from 'Transactions' table: no such column: 'Date' - Java Error

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to read from my database using Java imports `java.sql.PreparedStatement` and `java.sql.ResultSet`. My database has the column that I am trying to query but it gives me and error so i'm not sure how to fix this error.

`Database error - can't select data from 'Transactions' table: no such column: 'Date'
An error occurred! Database error - can't select data from 'Transactions' table: no such column: 'Date'`

The SQL statement that I am trying to use is `SELECT substr(Date, 4, 2), SUM(Price) FROM Transactions GROUP BY substr(Date, 4, 2)`. This statements works fine when run in SQLite Studio. I have tried using the statement in Java without using the `substr` function and It runs without errors however it doesn't provide the results required.

```
public static String selectAllMonth(List<Transaction> targetList) {
    targetList.clear();
    try {
        PreparedStatement statement2 = DatabaseConnection.newStatement(
                "SELECT substr(Date, 4, 2), SUM(Price) FROM Transactions GROUP BY substr(Date, 4, 2)"
        );

        if (statement2 != null) {
            ResultSet results2 = statement2.executeQuery();
            if (results2 != null) {
                while (results2.next()) {
                    targetList.add(new Transaction(0,null,results2.getString("Date"), results2.getDouble("Price"),0,null));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException resultsException) {
        String error = "Database error - can't select data from 'Transactions' table: " + resultsException.getMessage();
        Logger.log(error);
        return error;
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SELECT substr(Date, 4, 2) as 'Date', SUM(Price) as 'Price' FROM Transactions GROUP BY substr(Date, 4, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Bor Laze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54493431/642706) is correct to wrap your name with single-quote marks. But instead, I suggest you use all-lowercase with trailing underscore in your names: `date_`

Uppercase/lowercase in names of tables/columns/etc is tricky as most databases fail to follow the SQL standard. The standard says names should be converted to all-uppercase when assigning a name.

For maximum portability across various databases I suggest consistently using all-lowercase in your names, separating words with an underscore.

I also use a trailing underscore on every name as the SQL standard explicitly promises to never use that in a keyword of the language. This avoids collisions such as your `Date` name colliding with the `DATE` data type in the SQL language. Use `date_` instead and you’ll not need to wrap your names with quote marks `'Date'` as shown in the [Answer by Laze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54493431/642706).

Having to wrap your names all in quote marks quickly becomes tiresome and error-prone.